I'm trying to convert a long complicated word table to latex, and i find it hard to create the suitable code for it
I'm writing my thesis, and I need to write a long table with multiple merged cells in latex. I used several online table conversion tools but when the code is copied the table doesn't fit the page and it's all messed up.
. I need it to be in landscape layout and spanning different pages, without finding the words coming out of the cells.
Can you please help me out?
This is how far I've come
\documentclass[12pt, twoside,openright]{Thesis} 


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
{\theparagraph}{1em}{}


 \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\caption{Different green polymeric systems for prevention and treatment of liver diseases in literature }
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
\textbf{Nature of polymer} &
  \textbf{Formulation} &
  \textbf{Polymer} &
  \textbf{Drug} &
  \textbf{Method} &
  \textbf{Disease / model} &
  \textbf{PS (nm)} &
  \textbf{Main findings} &
  \textbf{Reference} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{9}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
%
\multirow{9}{*}{\textbf{Natural}} &
  NPs &
  CS &
  - &
  Coacervation &
  HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402)   implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) &
  40 – 100 nm &
  CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the   negative surface charge of BEL7402 cells shown as significant decrease in   cells’ zeta potential, thereby causing damage to the cell membrane. &
  \textbf{\cite{Qi2006,Qi2007}} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &
  NPs &
  CS &
  - &
  Coacervation &
  HCC (human HCC cell line BEL-7402) &
  52 - 73 nm &
  A mean of 52 \% inhibition rate of tumor   growth was observed with CSNPs at a low dose of 1 mg/kg/day. &
  \textbf{\cite{Xu2009}} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &
  Nanospheres &
  CS &
  Hydroxycamptothecin &
  Shirasu porous glass (SPG) membrane   emulsification technique &
  Liver Cancer (human hepatoma (HepG2)Cells) &
  250 – 430 nm &
  Marked reduction in microvessel density   and vascular endothelial growth factor provided direct evidence of the   antiangiogenic effect of CSNPs, in addition to their potential to induce   apoptosis in HCC cells. &
  \textbf{\cite{Han2014}} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &

............
.....
.....

\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}  



Please show how far you got yourself in creating the table.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I've modified the question showing how far i've done

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@cabohah, i've added all the needed packages, i'm writing my thesis and this is the last table i want to include.

To be compilable, you need to start with \documentclass and end with \end{document} so people can copy-paste-compile the code right away. Note that as is, nobody can sensibly answer because we have no idea what size the table has to fit. We don't know your paper size and we don't know the layout (e.g. how wide the margins are etc.). So you need to include any packages you're using the alter the page layout, too e.g. geometry.

The total width of your columns seems to be 20cm. The width of the table will be greater because you have to allow for the separation between the columns and the width of the vertical rules.

@cfr , is it clearer now ?

Well, Thesis.cls is not a standard class, so your code still can't be compiled. And you shouldn't include packages which aren't needed to reproduce the problem. Also, I don't have Times New Roman, for example, since it is a commercial font. Can you reproduce the problem using something from the standard TeX distributions? Off-topic: don't load inputenc, textcomp or anyfontsize. Don't load both pdflscape and lscape. Are you really using all those packages for tables?

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of LaTeX document classes called Thesis strewn across a multitude of websites. Which one do you employ? Is the class file available online?

@Mico
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-faculty-of-engineering-ain-shams-university/ykvrxppdjqmz
this is the online file

@MariamHesham - Thanks for your reply. I've gone ahead and (a) downloaded Thesis.cls from Overleaf and (b) updated my answer to now work with the Thesis document class.

@mico Thank you so so much
this helped me alot

There are a lot of info missing in your question (type of paper, margin size, packages used, documentclass, and without that information there is no garantee of what we propose will work in your side.
Anyway, there is an example of how you could do it using tabularray, asumming you are using a standard class, and margins of 1in.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtblr}[
    caption={table of example}
    ]{
    colspec = XXXXX[2]X[2]XX[3]X,
    width = \linewidth,
    hlines,vlines,
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries,l},
    }
    Nature of polymer & Formulation &  Polymer & Drug & Method & Disease (model) & PS (nm) & Main findings & References \\
    \SetCell[r=4,c=1]{h} Natural & NPs & CS & - & Coacervation & HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402) implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) & 40 -- 100 nm & CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the negative surface charge of .... & Insert cite \\
    & NPs & CS & - & Coacervation & HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402) implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) & 40 -- 100 nm & CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the negative surface charge of .... & Insert cite \\
    & NPs & CS & - & Coacervation & HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402) implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) & 40 -- 100 nm & CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the negative surface charge of .... & Insert cite \\
    & NPs & CS & - & Coacervation & HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402) implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) & 40 -- 100 nm & CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the negative surface charge of .... & Insert cite \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


Since the data you have provided is incomplete also, I don't know how  to best define the column types but here are a few suggestions:

X columns are expandable columns.
All X columns have the same width, but an X[2] column has double the width of a X column. And X[3], three times the width, and so.
If you want to manually adjust the width, use a p{width} column instead, where width is a valid TeX lenght (1cm, 0.5in, 120pt, etc.)
If you add more rows, you need to adjust the \SetCell command to increase the number of rows (r=number)


i have edited the post to include the missing info, but i'll try what you have proposed and see if it compiles in a good way, Thank you so much, i'm truly grateful to you

sorry for the inconvenience, i tried what you mentioned but i have 2 problems
the first one, since i have margins in the page so the available space is smaller, so when i compile, only two rows appear in each page, can i do something to increase the rows in one page, can i adjust the line spacing without affecting the rest of the document
the second one is that i want the table content to be aligned centrally, can i do this ?

You may want to suppress full justification in columns 6, 7, and 8.

(I updated this answer after receiving information about how to obtain a copy of Thesis.cls.)
Here's a xltabular-based solution. The xltabular machinery basically combines the capabilities of the longtable and tabularx packages, including the  capability of setting a target width for the table (here, set to \linewidth).
Note that I've deleted the various \textbf directives as I don't see a need to bold-face so much material in an otherwise well-designed table.

\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{Thesis} % per the OP's information
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,pdflscape,calc}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{\widthof{#1}}} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justification

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{nano-spheres hepa-toma hydro-xy-camp-to-the-cin}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\singlespacing
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth} % allow wide captions
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}  % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{%
       |P{Nature of}  % optimize widths of columns
       |P{Formu-}
       |P{Poly-}
       |P{Hydroxy-}
       |P{Shirasu porous}
       |P{subcutaneously}
       |l
       |L    % width of this column is a residual
       |P{Ref.} |}
       
       
%% headers and footers

\caption{Different green polymeric systems for prevention and 
         treatment of liver diseases in literature }
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
Nature of polymer & Formulation & Polymer & Drug & Method &
Disease\slash model & PS (nm) & Main findings & Ref. \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{9}{l}{\textsc{Table \thetable}, continued} \\[1ex]
\hline
Nature of polymer & Formulation & Polymer & Drug & Method &
Disease\slash model & PS (nm) & Main findings & Ref. \\
\hline
\endhead


\hline
\multicolumn{9}{r}{\small (continued on next page)} \\
\endfoot


\hline
\endlastfoot


%% Body of table

Natural &
  NPs &
  CS &
  -- &
  Coacervation &
  HCC (Human hepatoma cells (BEL7402) implanted subcutaneously into right flank of the nude mice) &
  40--100 &
  CSNPs had the ability to neutralize the negative surface charge of BEL7402 cells shown as significant decrease in cells' zeta potential, thereby causing damage to the cell membrane. &
  \cite{Qi2006, Qi2007} \\ 
  \cline{2-9} 
 &
  NPs &
  CS &
  -- &
  Coacervation &
  HCC (human HCC cell line BEL-7402) &
  52--73 &
  A mean of 52\,\% inhibition rate of tumor growth was observed with CSNPs at a low dose of 1\,mg/kg/day. &
  \cite{Xu2009} \\ 
  \cline{2-9} 
 &
  Nanospheres &
  CS &
  Hydroxycamptothecin &
  Shirasu porous glass (SPG) membrane emulsification technique &
  Liver Cancer (human hepatoma (HepG2) Cells) &
  250--430 &
  Marked reduction in microvessel density and vascular endothelial 
  growth factor provided direct evidence of the antiangiogenic effect 
  of CSNPs, in addition to their potential to induce apoptosis in 
  HCC cells. &
  \cite{Han2014} \\ 
\hline 
\dots & & & & & & & & \\


\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

